# How to show the Image in div using MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the following Controller Action for getting Image From DB

Controller

```
        public ActionResult GetPhoto()
        {
            string base64String = string.Empty;
            byte[] bDoccontent;
            byte[] byteArray;
            byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64String);
            var photo = (from doc in db.Photos
                         where doc.CandidateID == "S1404234570"
                         select doc).FirstOrDefault();
            bDoccontent = photo.ImageFile;
            base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bDoccontent, 0, bDoccontent.Length);
            byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64String);
            Stream obj = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(obj);
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sr.ReadToEnd());
            return File(buffer, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

View

```
    <div id="divUserImage">
    </div>
```

Now I need to Show the Image which is return from the Action in **divUserImage**.How to do this?

Comment: You can use <img> tag to do so. Specify your action path in source and it will display the image as expected

Comment: In addition if your action doesn't require any argument then you can do this trick with the help of css too. Just create a new Route Entry in your global.asax, which will redirect **YourDoomain.Com/Photo** to above action. This will quite simplify the thing more. But yeah it will not be a standard practice though but an intresting stuff.. Let me know if you need code for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are returning a JPEG image, you can put the URL of your action in to the `src` of an `img` element.

```
<div id="divUserImage">
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "MyController")" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to call that controller into image tag

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "YourController")" alt="" />
```